# Bit mapping conversion from C# to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to convert some C# code to VB.Net.  See the following:

C#:

```
private const ushort SO_IMAGE_RAW = 1;
private const ushort SO_IMAGE_DIB = 2;
private const ushort SO_IMAGE_DCM = 3;
private const ushort SO_IMAGE_BITDEPTH = 12;
private const ushort SO_IMAGE_FORMAT = SO_IMAGE_RAW;
int format = (SO_IMAGE_BITDEPTH << 16) + (SO_IMAGE_FORMAT & 0x0000FFFF);
```

From the watcher: format=786433    int
// This is correct value.

VB.Net:

```
Private Const SO_IMAGE_RAW As UShort = 1
Private Const SO_IMAGE_DIB As UShort = 2
Private Const SO_IMAGE_DCM As UShort = 3
Private Const SO_IMAGE_BITS As UShort = 12
Private Const SO_IMAGE_FORMAT = SO_IMAGE_RAW
Dim format As Integer = (SO_IMAGE_BITS << 16) + (SO_IMAGE_FORMAT And &HFFFF)
```

From the watcher: format=13    Integer
'' This is incorrect value.

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: I used a converter to get the VB.net code.

Comment: Converter used:
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

I tried several converters, but this one actually seemed more reasonable - still didn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the constants to integers and you get the same result as C#:

```
Private Const SO_IMAGE_RAW As Integer = 1
Private Const SO_IMAGE_DIB As Integer = 2
Private Const SO_IMAGE_DCM As Integer = 3
Private Const SO_IMAGE_BITDEPTH As Integer = 12
Private Const SO_IMAGE_FORMAT As Integer = SO_IMAGE_RAW
```

I'm not quite sure why this is necessary, but the following post might shed some light:
[Binary Shift Differences between VB.NET and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151333/binary-shift-differences-between-vb-net-and-c-sharp)

Another option - perhaps easier to stomach, is to keep the constants the same, but just use a cast:

```
Dim format As Integer = (CInt(SO_IMAGE_BITDEPTH) << 16) + (SO_IMAGE_FORMAT And &HFFFF)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to specify the datatype in this line

```
Private Const SO_IMAGE_FORMAT = SO_IMAGE_RAW
```

try changing it to

```
Private Const SO_IMAGE_FORMAT As UShort = SO_IMAGE_RAW
```

EDIT:

[this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) is also a great tool to convert `c#` code to `vb.net`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Const SO_IMAGE_RAW As UShort = 1
Private Const SO_IMAGE_DIB As UShort = 2
Private Const SO_IMAGE_DCM As UShort = 3
Private Const SO_IMAGE_BITDEPTH As UShort = 12
Private Const SO_IMAGE_FORMAT As UShort = SO_IMAGE_RAW
Private format As Integer = (SO_IMAGE_BITDEPTH << 16) + (SO_IMAGE_FORMAT And &Hffff)
```

[Convert C# to VB.NET link1](http://converter.telerik.com/)

[Convert C# to VB.NET link2](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)