# Bitwise shift vs Multiplication

Tags: .net, vb.net, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I often use bitwise operators in my job and write on VB.NET.
When create variable type of System.Byte, it is required type cast to shift byte left:

```
Dim a As Byte = &HFF
Dim b As Integer = a * 256
Debug.WriteLine(b.ToString("X")) 
Dim c As Integer = a << 8 'without cast'
Debug.WriteLine(c.ToString("X"))
Dim d As Integer = CInt(a) << 8 'with cast'
Debug.WriteLine(d.ToString("X"))
```

The output is:

> FF00
>
> FF
>
> FF00

Using "*256" allows skip type casting, and code looks shorter, especially if few shifts in one expression are used. But such kind of record not looks clear unlike shift.

So question is what type is preferably in the same case? Is multiplication takes more processor time or not?

Comment: Doesn't the multiplication also contain an implicit cast from `byte` to `int`?

Comment: @Rotem Shure. But expression is shorter.

Comment: Seems this behavior is specific to vb.net. In c# all of the expressions result in `0xFF00`, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151333/binary-shift-differences-between-vb-net-and-c-sharp

Comment: @Rotem yes, i've also checked it. But is there some objective recommendations or it is just choice of developer taste?

Comment: @Rotem thanks for the link, interesting.

Comment: It is an oddity in vb.net, specific to the << and >> operators.  The language specification mentions it in chapter 11.18: "Unlike the other binary operators, the result type of a shift operation is determined as if the operator was a unary operator with just the left operand. The type of the right operand must be implicitly convertible to Integer and is not used in determining the result type of the operation."  It doesn't otherwise explain why they made this choice, none is obvious.  Using CInt() to promote the type explicitly is the correct solution.

Comment: @Aave : I'd say it's a choice of taste. With older, low-cost processors bit shifting was much faster than regular math, but with 21st century processors the performance difference is negligible/non-existant. Nowadays everything's so optimized.

Comment: In terms of what's preferable, unless you have identified this piece of code as being an actual bottleneck when profiling your code and you code is actually time critical, you should probably just use multiplication as it will be a lot easier to maintain. (although, if your intent is actually bit-shifting, to make a bit mask for example, then your intent would actually probably be clearer if you actually use bit shifting)

Comment: Most optimizing compilers will implement `* 256`using a shift anyway, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've loaded this VB code into decompiler ILSpy, and that was shown:

```
IL_0001: ldc.i4 255
IL_0006: stloc.0

// 255 * 256
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: ldc.i4 256
IL_000d: mul.ovf
IL_000e: stloc.1 //equal part starts
IL_000f: ldloca.s 1
IL_0011: ldstr "X"
IL_0016: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString(string)
IL_001b: call void [System]System.Diagnostics.Debug::WriteLine(string)

// 255 << 8
IL_0021: ldloc.0
IL_0022: ldc.i4.8
IL_0023: ldc.i4.7
IL_0024: and
IL_0025: shl
IL_0026: conv.u1
IL_0027: stloc.2 //equal part starts
IL_0028: ldloca.s 2
IL_002a: ldstr "X"
IL_002f: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString(string)
IL_0034: call void [System]System.Diagnostics.Debug::WriteLine(string)

// cint(255) << 8
IL_003a: ldloc.0
IL_003b: ldc.i4.8
IL_003c: shl
IL_003d: stloc.3 //equal part starts
IL_003e: ldloca.s 3
IL_0040: ldstr "X"
IL_0045: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString(string)
IL_004a: call void [System]System.Diagnostics.Debug::WriteLine(string)
```

As you can see, 5 last strings of IL code are equal for each high-level instructions. Difference is only at top of each part. And **0xFF*256** contains only 3 operators, **CInt(0xFF)<<8** contains 3 operators, and **0xFF<<8** contains 6 operators, i.e. 2 more times! Bitwise shift without type casting use bit mask for reject possible overflow, what appends additional operators into the IL code.

Also, i've found in the book of Francesco Balena "Programming Microsoft Visual Basic 2005: The language" that bitwise shift is faster for Long and ULong types. For Integer and Short types bitwise shift is equals to  multiplication.

So my conclusion is:

- for Long and ULong bitwise shift is faster than multiplication;
- for all other types (with type cast to result bitness) multiplication is faster or equals to bitwise shift, so using of first or second case is only developer's taste.